# GIT: Checkout file of other branch and automatically prefix it with branch name

Tags: git, version-control

To gather some stuff from different branches, I'd like to have the file from differnt branches simultaneously present in my editor.

**Is it possible to checkout the same file from different branches and automatically prefix/suffix each of them with the branch they are from?**

Such that I end up with the following file structure:

```
myProject/myfile.cpp // version of currently checked-out branch
myProject/branch1-myfile.cpp // versions from other branches
myProject/branch2-myfile.cpp
myProject/branch3-myfile.cpp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no magic git command that will do this, but as with many automation tasks a short shell script would take care of it...

```
for branch in branch1 branch2 branch3; do
    git show $branch:myfile.cpp > $branch-myfile.cpp
done
```